I want to check the typeOf of the value inputted in an input field
I want to check whether the inputted value by the user is String Or Integer
const inp = document.querySelector('input')
console.log(typeof inp.value)

Even if the user inputs a number,it gives string only
If the user inputs a string,it also gives string

Your question asks about 'string or integer' and there seems to be confusion in the answers given so far - interpreting 'integer' as meaning 'number'. Are you definitely wanting to test for an integer, not just any number?

Yeah,i get your point, i want to check whether it is  a "number" or a "string" or an "alphabet"

Might be good to edit your question to make it very plain what you want to test for. If you mean a number then I assume something like 2.3 or 2e3 would comply. What does “alphabet” mean here? Is it upper and/or lowercase A-z only?

use regular expression to check for integer



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const inp = document.querySelector('#userInput');
    
    if (inp) {
        inp.addEventListener('input', () => {
            const inputValue = inp.value;
            const isInteger = /^\d+$/.test(inputValue);

            if (isInteger) {
                console.log('integer.');
            } else {
                console.log('string.');
            }

            //convert integer 
            if (isInteger) {
                const integerValue = parseInt(inputValue, 10);
                console.log('Converted integer value:', integerValue);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.error('not found.');
    }
});
  <input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="Enter a value">




This will not recognize 2e4 as a Number, which it is.

In JavaScript, the value property of an input element always returns a string, regardless of the user's input. Therefore, typeof inp.value;, will always return string.
To check the actual type of the input value, you can first convert the input to a number then check if the conversion was successful like the following way:
...
const numberValue = Number(inp.value);

if (!isNaN(numberValue) && inp.value.trim() !== '') {
  console.log('Input is a number');
} else {
  console.log('Input is a string');
}
...


The HTMLInputElement's value property returns string by default

value: A string that represents the current value of the control. If the user enters a value different from the value expected, this may return an empty string.

You can check the available API's for HTMLInputElement here.
You could use the valueAsNumber property which would return the numeric value or NaN.

valueAsNumber: A number that represents the value of the element, interpreted as one of the following, in order: A time value, a number, or NaN if conversion is impossible.

Examples


  console.log(inp.valueAsNumber); // NaN
  console.log(inp2.valueAsNumber); //12345 as number

  console.log(isNaN(inp.valueAsNumber)); // true
  console.log(isNaN(inp2.valueAsNumber)); // false
<body>
  <input type="text" name="" id="text-input" value="test">
  <input type="number" name="" id="number-input" value="12345">
</body>




To achieve this, you can try converting the user input to an integer. If it goes success that means the user has entered an integer. Otherwise, string.
You can follow this example:


if (!isNaN(inp) && inp.trim() !== "") {
                const numberValue = Number(inp);
                resultElement.textContent = `Input is a number: ${numberValue}`;
            } else {
                resultElement.textContent = `Input is a string: "${inp}"`;
            }




The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the value property of an HTML input element always returns a string, regardless of whether the input appears to be a intiger.
<input type="text" id="inputField" placeholder="Enter a value">
        <script>
            const inp = document.querySelector('#inputField');
    
            inp.addEventListener('input', () => {
                const value = inp.value.trim();
                if (/^-?\d+$/.test(value)) {
                    console.log('Integer');
                } else {
                    console.log('String');
                }
            });
        </script>


When you retrieve a value from an HTML input element using JavaScript, it always returns a string. To determine if the user input is actually a number or a string, you can use additional checks to test the content of the input.

From a comment, there are three possible results: a number, a string with alphabetic characters only, another string.
There are several ways a number can be input in JS (examples: 2, 2.3, 2e3) and if the number is very large (or small) there is the possibility that it represents Infinity (or -Infinity) which I assmume in this snippet is considered a number (as it is considered a number by JS).
The snippet first tests for number using isNaN and then tests for alphabetic letters only using a regex.


const input = document.querySelector('input');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const str = input.value;
  const num = Number(str);
  let message;
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    message = 'it is a number = ' + num;
  } else if (regex.test(str)) {
    message = 'it is an alphabetic-only string - ' + str;
  } else {
    message = 'it is neither a number nor an alphabetic-only string = ' + str;
  }
  console.log(message);
});
<input>
<button>Click me to see whether the input is a number, an alphabetic string or another string</button>



